# how to set the bitmap to the ImageView in main.xml captured from the camera?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I have a Imageview in main.xml, how to set the bitmap the to the imageView in main.xml 
i can assign bitmap to the local image view in the below code.

```
//Activates the Camera
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

//  get the bitmap data from the Camera
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap b = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
int width = b.getWidth();
int height = b.getHeight();
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageBitmap(b);

//Saves the  image
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, timestamp, timestamp);

// Set the View
setContentView(img);
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble understanding how you structured your app but here are my suggestions:

Change your `setContentView(img);` to `setContentView(R.id.main);`

Then do:

```
ImageView mImg;
mImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.(your xml img id));
mImg.setImageBitmap(img);
```

Comment: this will sets to imagview background. how to set vitmap to imageview source